# Redux-Persist is not rehydrating the state or not saving the state properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using `redux-persist` in an `react-native` App. However, the state is either not persisted or no rehydrated properly.

This is how I try to persist the store

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {MMKV} from 'react-native-mmkv';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

// https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/blob/master/docs/WRAPPER_REDUX.md
const storage = new MMKV();
const reduxStorage = {
  setItem: (key, value) => {
    storage.set(key, value);
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  },
  getItem: key => {
    const value = storage.getString(key);
    return Promise.resolve(value);
  },
  removeItem: key => {
    storage.delete(key);
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
};

// https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: reduxStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};

const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];

// redux debugger for flipper
if (__DEV__) {
  const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default;
  middlewares.push(createDebugger());
}

const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  settings,
  data,
  user,
  database,
});

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combinedReducer);
export const store = createStore(pReducer, composedEnhancer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Working with `react` in the browser, I would see a `@@hydrate` (or something similar) action dispatched when the store is rehydrated. However, I cannot observer something similar on the flipper debugger. Am I setting redux wrongly?